# Yocto vs Petalinux Tools

Tags: yocto, petalinux

Me and my team are currently working with Yocto and Petalinux Tools ( from Xilinx) to develop a distribution based on the Xilinx Linux kernel. At first glance both look the same and there is little to differentiate between the two(but that could be due to our inexperience)

One thing we know is that Petalinux uses packages from Yocto project at its centre and uses it for kernel config and distribution development.

So what is it that is so different about them and are there advantages to use either of them ?